# Redux dispatch action not firing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am trying to trigger this redux action but whenever I check the value of my reducer's payload, it's always "undefined" for some reason. This only makes me think that the action is not firing and I cannot understand why. Here is my action:

```
export const getAllSubmittedRequests = (people: PersonalData[]) => (dispatch: any) => {
  let count = 0;
  people?.forEach((person) => {
    if (person.isEntered === true) {
      count++;
    }
  });

  dispatch(getAllSubmittedRequestsSuccess(count === people?.length ? true : false));
};
```

**getAllSubmittedRequestsSuccess:**

```
export const getAllSubmittedRequestsSuccess = (enteredRequests: boolean) => ({ type: GET_ENTERED_REQUESTS, enteredRequests});
```

Here is the section of the reducer which is pretty straight forward:

```
case GET_ENTERED_REQUESTS:
  return { ...state, enteredRequests: action.enteredRequests};
```

I call my action inside an **useEffect** hook in the component like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllSubmittedRequests(props.data.people);
  }, [props.data.people]);
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong with **getAllSubmittedRequests** and why the **dispatch** section is not firing inside the action function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're creating a function and throwing it away. `getAllSubmittedRequests(...)` returns a function that takes the `dispatch` function as an argument. You forgot to call it:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
    getAllSubmittedRequests(props.data.people)(dispatch);
}, [props.data.people]);
```

Comment: No, that's a thunk and the redux-thunk middleware will take care of that. It should really be called `dispatch(getAllSubmittedRequests(props.data.people))`

Comment: @phry I've never used the thunk middleware, but I assume it hooks the action pipeline looking for functions. Makes sense. Given the absence of this info in the question, I'm happy to leave this as is and keep the relevancy of thunk middleware here in the comments.